# Rails bootstrap delete confirmation with modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do a bevore action while clicking on a link. It should display a bootstrap modal with cancel and delete button.

code lookslike this:

Delete Button

```
<button class="btn btn-default" data-href="<%= url_for(:action => :delete, :id => @vid.id) %>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalBox">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <%= t "movies.add.delete" %>
          </button>
```

Modal Code is in application.html.erb -> modal is empty. I set the buttons on page load with jquery. that works fine.

```
    $(".modal-footer").html("<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Cancel</button> <a class='btn btn-danger btn-ok'>Delete</a>");
```

and the code for the modal to wait is this:

```
$("#modalBox").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

whats my problem in this case?

I've got the code example from here: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/NePR0BQf3VmKtuMmhVR7?p=preview

thanks

Problem is:
Modal is shown for less than 100ms ^^ .. and the deletion is performed

Comment: Demo seems to work fine in 2 different browsers. What are you expecting to happen differently?

Comment: nothing different^^ want the same as in the demo. But with my own pasted code it dosn't work

Comment: modal dissapears without the cance to see or click a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to do it this way:

```
<button class="btn btn-default deletebtn" data-href="<%= url_for(:action => :delete, :id => @vid.id) %>" onclick="check();return false;">
     <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> <%= t "movies.add.delete" %>
</button>
```